# Detect when resistor value changes without a microcontroller

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I have a sensor that has two pins. The resistance value of that sensor is 1.6 kiloohms. I want to detect when the resistance of the sensor changes to 300 ohms. In other words the sensor resistance changes from 1600 ohms to 300 ohms.

I want to have a digital 1 (LED on) when the sensor has a resistance of 300 ohms and a digital 0 (LED off) when sensor has a resistance of 1.6 kiloohms.**

The circuit below is what I have tried with a transistor. It did not work. Where should I start from? I can try OP amps with help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKmSt2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: While the comparator answers work, it is possible with 1 transistor, if you put the sensor inline with the 10k, from base to Gnd. However, the value of 10k depends sensitively on the supply voltage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a comparator (or just an op amp with no feedback) for this. Set up two voltage dividers, one with your sensor and one with a reference resistance. The voltage in the sensor divider will be either above or below the reference divider. The comparator will convert this difference to a fixed high or low voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyuC36.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Pretty similar. ;-)

Comment: I'll throw my two cents in for including some hysteresis in there since this sensor sounds like it could be a thermistor or something similar with a slowly changing output.

Comment: Current limiting for the LED?

Comment: @hacktastical It's just a conceptual diagram. :-)

Answer (score 12):

A comparator or op-amp can do this. Generally, you will want to add some hysteresis to the circuit so that it doesn't flicker needlessly.

Here's something that works, with some added hysteresis to make the indicator reject noise ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxASSsgoFMBaMMAKACcQAWDvEbBFXng69%20UXrnjMASp2KEQc2fMLCaNDjWJi10BMw0RshHigTyOKkKfkQ8AHQDOYBI8Yun8eI47QUKYmDERlwcYCgcxCjevth4%20IREeIRw3MSOYJ5qjmjpmZngjpDMAO6cltZKVmZQJZWBAhHyFUXsjeDJlYo0mHDMYAl1HW31ViAAJrQAZgCGAK4ANgAu9PO0Y%20DaULAspW0VbXwCRbuKh5zcIke1scJnd6LHl1YYAkYmLzXsFeHd1WAY8hoYSMtTaigqXVqEKafzCnyqTQ0CN4kFUyEkpTeViR3yRRQA5sjcMIKtg0No2OAuCjhGBqT8xBlJIS6bdUVTbuS1JTWdigdT-oCFAhsLVeeDqpDSuKbAK4Y80CYkbyGQr8HyrOqzmqePdXg9rqI9c8rl8-gDkUwjujeuxeYKOeB5TaigAjDUO-xIFDYVTMAAeKKQYDwPFCEECEFpAgAyrQAHYOAD2rEcUloDgAlg5FtN4wBjWjMd1hAT-WlYKxkmqBxhApJO7DgPBaaMgdOTWisBOFtMZ7O5gtF2JOsQSdpwdv9nN5wvMIA)):

[image]

Note that the comparator is an open-collector type (e.g., LM339) and will be low when the (-) input is higher than the (+) input. This will be the case when the sensor resistor is higher than the reference value. With the hysteresis, the LED lights when the sensor resistance drops below about 690 ohms, and turns off when it’s above about 1250 ohms.

(Why the extra 10k resistors on the low side? To reduce current and allow greater hysteresis.)

Comment: This is a good example to illustrate a subtle point in analog design. It well work (especially in simulation), but it's not great practice- the sensitivity to the top 10K resistor values is unnecessarily high. A relatively small +/-2% or so error in those resistors in the wrong ways (one high, one low) is sufficient to cause it to never switch, even though we have a more than 5:1 change in sensor resistance.

Comment: Yes, the resistors could be scaled down a bit.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an op-amp such as the LM358:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIM8Gl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can add an RC to the inverting input if the signal might be noisy. You can also add a taste of hysteresis by feeding back the output to the non-inverting input through a resistor. I've picked 680\$\Omega\$ for the switching point.

Here's a simulation with the sensor going from 1.6K to 300 ohms at t= 500msec:

[image]

This is a bridge configuration with a comparator- since R1 = R5 the circuit switches when the sensor is the same value as R4. R6 controls the LED current. R1 and R5 are picked to give a decent voltage across the sensor without drawing excessive current from the supply.

Edit: As @BenVoigt mentions, this measuring circuit is called a Wheatstone bridge in honour of Sir Charles Wheatstone FRS (though he didn't invent it, another fellow named Christie did a decade or so earlier than Wheatstone's seminal lecture in 1843. Some speculate the the name comes from a similarity to a Chinese bridge used in [chinoiserie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willow_pattern) of that era in England.

Others are dubious and think it was simply because the galvanometer bridged the sides of the diamond. The picture below is from the IEE History of Technology book "Sir Charles
Wheatstone FRS 1802–1875"

[image]

Many of the original applications of the bridge were for AC (continuous and transient) measurements and there are many adaptations that have various advantages and disadvantages, including the well-known Blumlein and Wein bridges.

Comment: Of course this is a Wheatstone bridge, just a bit hard to see because it isn't drawn in the conventional diamond.